# First time I navigate to Panorama Page it gets too long to load

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, panorama-control

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7.1 application which has a panorama page.

This panorama page has two panorama items one with two textblock and the other one with a bing map control. And I also set a 1,5MB image as panorama control background.

This is Panorama's XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="XxXClass.DemoDetail"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" Foreground="{x:Null}" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps">
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut"/>
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <controls:Panorama Title="Demonstation Tracker">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/demonstrationPanorama.png"/>
            </controls:Panorama.Background>

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Details">
                <Grid Background="#73000000" Margin="0,0,0,26">
                    <TextBlock Height="42" Margin="8,8,174,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="XXXX" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="8,54,8,8" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="413" Width="381" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"><Run Text="xxx."/><Run Text=".."/></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item two-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Map">
                <Grid>
                    <my:Map Name="map1" Margin="0,0,0,26" Height="420" Width="420" />
                </Grid>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>

    <!--Panorama-based applications should not show an ApplicationBar-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

First time I navigate to panorama page I gets too long to show, and if I tap on back button and I come back to it, it loads more quickly.

**How can I make to panorama's page loads faster?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to comment Map control. I'm sure that the problem with Map control. 
I always make  data  initialization in a background thread. Then when data are ready make BeginInvoke and redraw UI. And sure 1.5 MB is too Big, reduce it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now image is 363Kb and panorama page needs two or three seconds to load. And, if I comment map control it loads faster.

Comment: make visibility.collapsed by default for the map then get data in background thread after that put visibility = visible. Do not forget use BeginInvoke. Ore U can just init map for Pageloaded event.

Comment: Pageloaded event doesn't exit on Windows Phone.

Comment: it calls Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"

Answer (score 3):

1.5Mb is way too big. At runtime the image will be decompressed and stored in the memory. It is fast for the second time because it is already in memory. If you target devices with 256Mb ram you will have to reduce the memory usage.

Try these:

- Use compressed jpeg. Try to minimalize the file size.
- Background images should be between 480 x 800 pixels and 1024 x 800 pixels (width x height) to ensure good performance, minimal load time, and no scaling.
- Background image should be a resource.
- Disable toolkit animation
- Limit the PanoramaItems to 4

Because of usability I would also consider to move bing maps to a non-slide enabled page.

Comment: could you please tell, why making background image resource is better then content?

Comment: If you’re using Panorama, a Resource background will load immediately compared to Content. This is because the image is loaded to the memory when the application starts.  Obviously it will have impact on the start-up time.

Comment: Now, image is 363Kb and it still gets too long to load. If I remove map control it loads decently. If I load map on `Panorama_SelectionChanged` event (when I move to second panorama item` it stills freezes UI for a second or two. Is there something similar to Android's `AsyncTask` to avoid this problem?